# How do I conditionally select DIVs that appear on top each page on 'print' mode?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a page which is created dynamically with the user interaction, with many `DIV`s with variable sizes and other nested components. Some of them are displayed side by side, some will display on the next line. Once I call `window.print()`, they are reorganized by each browser, with the help of

```css
@media print { .myDiv { page-break-inside: avoid; } }
```

I want to add a header with image on top of each print page, but using  `position: fixed` won't work on Chrome or Safari (as of 03-31-2016). I don't want to calculate page size or components heights, since the user can always change the margins.

Considering I can dynamically add another `<div class="print-header">` before each `<div class="myDiv">`, I *would want* something like this:

```css
@media print { 
  .print-header { display: none; } 
  .print-header:first-of-the-page { display: block; } /*pseudo css*/
}
```

JS solution is acceptable too.

---

**More Details** *[added on 04-01-2016]*

**Original problem:** to set a logo (`<img>`) as header of all printing pages on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE11 (bonus).

**Option 1:** using an HTML5 API. ***NOT AVAILABLE***

**Option 2:** using `@media print { .print-header{ position: fixed}}` to show the element on all the printing pages  ***GOOD FOR FF and IE ONLY***

On Chrome and Safari it only shows it on the 1st page . See a code sample on MDN's [Printing a document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Media#Action.3A_Printing_a_document)

[image: Printing header using fixed position]

**Option 3:** Add header based on sizes and position calculated at print time. ***ERROR PRONE***

This means calculating the `width` and `height` of all components to forecast which of them will fit in on a print page, then add a `jQuery.clone()` of the header element on a position defined by `pageHeight + i`, where `i` is 0, 1, .. `n` and `n` is  the # of pages on the printed document.

**Option 4:** Conditionally select the element which shows on the top of the print page. ***INITIAL QUESTION***

In CSS I can use [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) to get the 1st child of a type under a given parent. Is there any similar way to getting the 1st child on each print page? Is there a way to know, at print time, what belongs to each page, using CSS or JS?

---

**Related Links**

Apparently they won't provide a definite solution, but I may have missed something:

1. [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page)
2. [Print footer on every printed page from website, across all browsers (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758339/print-footer-on-every-printed-page-from-website-across-all-browsers-chrome/)
3. [Having Google Chrome repeat table headers on printed pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211229/having-google-chrome-repeat-table-headers-on-printed-pages/22089785)
4. [How to apply some styles to first and last elements on a print page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526142/how-to-apply-some-styles-to-first-and-last-elements-on-a-print-page/17527723)
5. [Using CSS and/or jQuery for Printed Pages with Page Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878013/using-css-and-or-jquery-for-printed-pages-with-page-breaks)

---

*Action: Printing a document by [Mozilla Contributors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Media$history) is licensed under [CC-BY-SA 2.5](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/).*

Comment: This is a great question.  If you can include a little more detail and an example of a specific situation (maybe a picture of the webpage? or a jsfiddle?) and what exactly you would want printed, I think your post will get more attention.

Comment: Related, but doesn't contain any JS solutions for Chrome/Safari: [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page)

Comment: Details and contextualization added. Thx, @mareoraft

Comment: I added other related links directly on the question  Thx.

Comment: A related feature in Chrome is [preview mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode)

Comment: Showing header on all pages was [fixed on Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample on how to accomplish the previous task with HTML and CSS:

```html
<div id="print-header">
    <img src="img/logo.png" width="200px" height="50px" >
</div>
```

```css
#print-header{    display: none;  }
@media print {
    #print-header {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0pt;
        left: 0pt;
        right: 0pt;
        text-align: right;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: 
*Showing header on all pages was [fixed on Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826)*

Comment: As of today, now the logo is shown on all pages on FF and Chrome; it still doesn't show on Safari.